# Create prompt '+ create new +' is not displayed when filter returns no values

Tags: webform-civicrm, contact-reference

I've created a test-form with two contact, for the first contact,one of the parents i'm using the contact id from url.
for the second contact there is a filter Relationship to: contact-1, specify relationship: Child of contact-1

- When the filters return one or more childs, the options '+ create new +' and '- select -' are available. As expected.
- But when the filters returns no value, there should be the possibilty  to select '+ create new +', as this is the configured value for create prompt. But this option is not in the select list.

Please advise on how to get parents, the choice to create a new child contact record?

thanks,
Paul

please advice

[image: Filter returns results = can also select '+ create new +']

[image: Filter returns empty = '+ create new +' is not in the select list]